# Magento 2.2.4 + Database migration Undefined offset: 1 vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 291

Tags: magento2, database-migration

I am doing database migration from magento 1.9.3.7 to magento 2.2.4.

When i run below command

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset path of config.xml
```

Then below issue is occur's

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 291

When i re-run command then

Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-Migration_Default' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_
  NAME'

i have reinstall magento fresh Database and again i have found these issue.

Please suggest me how it can fix.

Comment: hi @Trliok, could you find any solution for this?

Comment: Issue still present in March 2020. @see https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/813

Comment: any solution for this?